# Angular / Ivy error : Error: Token InjectionToken XXXXXXXXX is missing a ɵprov definition

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

Getting the error after updating to Angular 9 / Ivy compiler

```
ERROR Error: Token InjectionToken XXXXXXXXX is missing a ɵprov definition.
    at injectableDefOrInjectorDefFactory (vendor.js:47105)
    at providerToFactory (vendor.js:47210)
    at resolveProvider$1 (vendor.js:56430)
```

Comment: i'm also facing the same issue with angular fire module, but there are no injector in app module, Error: Token InjectionToken angularfire2.app.nameOrConfig is missing a ɵprov definition.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can occur if you try to explicitly override an inherited injectable with `undefined` or `null`.

In Angular 8 this was ok

```
    {
        provide: AMBIENT_CART,
        useExisting: undefined
    }
```

With Angular 9 it needs to be changed to

```
    {
        provide: AMBIENT_CART,
        useValue: undefined
    }
```

If you're curious: In my case I was doing this for safety reasons, to make sure I didn't use this particular injectable by mistake.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error when running ng test after upgrading from Angular 8 --> 9:
"Error: Token InjectionToken apiToken is missing a ɵprov definition."

My solution to this was very simple- there was a typo in the spec file that I guess didn't matter in Angular 8, but does in Angular 9? The last instance of 'useValue' below was incorrectly written 'usevalue'. Such an obscure error!

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({ 
    imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ], 
    providers: [ 
        { provide: ApiService, useValue: apiService }, 
        { provide: ProductsApiService, useValue: productsService }, 
        { provide: apiToken, useValue: mockApiToken } 
    ] 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I started receiving this error while running unit tests after upgrading an application from Angular 8 to Angular 10. The issue occurred because the existing spec file was using `value` instead of `useValue` in the providers array as shown in the below sample. Fixed the issue by changing it to `useValue`.

```
    beforeEach(async(() => {
    void TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
            MockPipe(TranslatePipe),
        ],
        imports: [
            HttpClientTestingModule,
        ],
        providers: [
            FormBuilder,
            MessageService,
            { provide: MESSAGES_TOKEN, value: {} }, //changed to useValue
        ]
    }).compileComponents();
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I updated **Angular** to version **>= 9** (*Token InjectionToken XxXxXxXx is missing a ɵprov definition*), especifically when I ran tests and these tests had providers as **MatDialogRef** and **MAT_DIALOG_DATA** from *Angular Material*.

My solution was replace the providers config in the *beforeEach()* section. look at:

***Before***:

```
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                    imports : [
                        ...
                    ],
                    declarations: [
                        ...
                    ],
                    providers: [
                        { provide: MatDialogRef },
                        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA }
                    ]
            }).compileComponents();

    }));
```

***After***:

```
import { MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/dialog';

beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                    imports : [
                        ...
                    ],
                    declarations: [
                        ...
                    ],
                    providers: [{
                        provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {hasBackdrop: false}
                    }]
            }).compileComponents();
```